GCVirtualController triggers didMove twice
New iOS person here..
Trying to incorporate GCVirtualController into my test code.
When I do, I see didMove getting called twice, thus causing lots of down-stream problems.  As soon as I comment out the controller, it only calls didMove once.
        let controllerConfig = GCVirtualController.Configuration()
        controllerConfig.elements = [ GCInputDirectionPad ]

        let controller = GCVirtualController(configuration: controllerConfig)
        controller.connect()
        virtualController = controller
        let movementHandler: GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler = { dPad, xValue, yValue in
            self.movePlayer(x: xValue, y: yValue)
        }

        if let gamePad = virtualController?.controller?.extendedGamepad {
            gamePad.dpad.valueChangedHandler = movementHandler
        }

Also found that if I do not define any valueChangedHandler, then it just seems call didMove over, and over.
Not seeing much when I google for GCVirtualController examples.
I tried changing around start up order, ect.   Nothing helped
